# How to cancel application without task in background

Tags: java, android, task

Hi I am making app when I am using Media player function. And when for example I close app this media still working in background. How to stop whole tasks in app?

```
                    final Random rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
                    tv3.setText(kombosy[new Random().nextInt(kombosy.length)]);

                    int resourceID=R.raw.rin1;

                    switch (tv3.getText().toString()) {
                        case "1-2":
                            resourceID =  R.raw.rin1;

                            break;
                        case "1-1-2":
                            resourceID =  R.raw.rin2;

                            break;
                        case "1-2-3-2":
                            resourceID =  R.raw.rin3;
                            break;
                        case "1-2-5-2":
                            resourceID =  R.raw.rin4;

                            break;
                        case "1-6-3-2":
                            resourceID =  R.raw.rin5;

                            break;
                        case "2-3-2":
                            resourceID =  R.raw.rin6;

                            break;


                    }
                    plyer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resourceID);
                    plyer.start();


                }
```

Comment: You should call mediaplayer stop and close before finishing your activity. If you need more help please post some code here to identify where you are facing issue

Comment: I eddited my question

Answer (score 1):

Create media player instance globally

```
MediaPlayer player;
```

Your switch case should look like this

You can get your ringtone resource ID in switch-case statement, then create a single media player object.

```
int resourceID = R.raw.rin1;
switch (tv3.getText().toString()) {
    case "1-2":
        resourceID =  R.raw.rin1;
        break;
    case "1-1-2":
        resourceID =  R.raw.rin2;
        break;
    case "1-2-3-2":
        resourceID =  R.raw.rin3;
        break;
    case "1-2-5-2":
        resourceID =  R.raw.rin4;
        break;
    case "1-6-3-2":
        resourceID =  R.raw.rin5;
        break;
    case "2-3-2":
        resourceID =  R.raw.rin6;
        break;
}
```

Create a `MediaPlayer` instance just like this

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceID);
player.start();
```

To stop your media player call this method :

```
private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: where I should out this code       player = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceID);
    player.start();

Comment: Becouse when I am putting this after my switch case function I get this error

Comment: no suitable method found for create(<anonymous CountDownTimer>,int)
                        plyer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resourceID);

Comment: You should create media player after switch case statement.

Comment: Still not working I edited my code in my question

Comment: Where did you called stopPlaying?

Comment: there where I always put public void after all text

Comment: Answer that I share is working fine here. You should find out where you were missed to call stopPlaying() method.